# Flutter - Displaying Admob Adverts and Google Maps on the same screen

Tags: google-maps, flutter, admob, google-maps-flutter, firebase-admob

I have a flutter app utilising firebase_admob and google_maps_flutter.

These two packages do not seem to be able to coexist on the same screen.

My app displays an application wide Advert that sits underneath the Bottom Navigation bar and persists when different screens / widgets are displayed.

When the Google Map tab is selected, the advert disappears leaving blank space.  It automatically reappears when you switch from the map tab.  Although this is not a major problem it does look a bit dodgey!

I originally used the admob_flutter package but instead of closing the advert when the map screen was selected, the graphics for the entire app became corrupt, replacing images with black squares and rendering strange artefacts everywhere.

I was wondering if anyone had come across this issue and what they did to work around it.

I am currently on the master channel of flutter as this seems to have resolved some other issues I had with maps crashing the app entirely.

Thanks in advance.